# How to get flavor in buildType of build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have my gradle file as below, where I sign my app as Debug in debug build, and Release in release build. It has two flavor i.e. Develop and Production.

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

productFlavors {
    develop {
        // Do something
    }
    production {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

However, I'm thinking of signing as Debug for Develop flavor (release) as well. How could I achieve that (i.e. access the flavor type variable in the buildType)?

Comment: do you want to get developDebug.apk with signing?

Comment: developDebug is still signing as Debug. but developRelease should be signing as Debug too (since I don't want it to be releasable... but just optimized with Proguard etc)

Comment: I see, but I'm wondering you set your signingConfig debug, why you wanna build developRelease with debug signing? It doesn't make a sense.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you want something like this:

```
developDebug: signingConfigs.debug
productionDebug: signingConfigs.debug
developRelease: signingConfigs.debug
productionRelease: signingConfigs.release
```

You can achieve it this way:

```
android {
  productFlavors {
    develop {
        // Do something
    }
    production {
        // Do something
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    // Make an unfinished release build type
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    // Finish the release build type flavor specific
    def runTasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.toString().toLowerCase()
    if (runTasks.contains("develop")) {
      release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
      }
    } else if (runTasks.contains("production")) {
      release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: I think this might be a cleaner solution**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    release-develop {
        initWith buildTypes.release
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

You could also use:

```
productFlavors.develop.signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
```

inside of your release build type.

**Original Answer:**

Something like this should do the trick.

The hierarchy goes buildTypes -> defaultConfig -> productFlavors

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}

productFlavors {
    develop {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        // Do something
    }
    production {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

- **developDebug**: signed with debug key from debug variant
- **developRelease**: signed with debug key in develop flavor
- **productionDebug**: signed with debug key from debug variant
- **productionRelease**: signed with release key from defaultConfig since its not defined in release variant.

Comment: When I have something like `release-develop`, it error out during execution, not recognizing it.

Comment: @Elye I was missing the buildTypes object, see my updated answer.  You need to set it using `initWith buildTypes.release`